# exim4: queue_run_max: not found

Tags: smtp, exim

I need to manage the number of outgoing concurrent SMTP connections - other mail servers are complaining that I have more than 50 concurrent connections and throttling my outgoing mail.

I googled and found the "queue_run_max" option, which sounded like what I need.  From my reading it is supposed to go in exim4.conf, but I don't one of those, perhaps because I'm using a split configuration file.  Anyways, most of my options are in update-exim4.conf.conf so I added it to this file.  I then restarted exim4 and got this message:

```
root@ds6419:/etc/exim4# /etc/init.d/exim4 restart
[....] Stopping MTA for restart:/usr/sbin/update-exim4.conf: 36: /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf: queue_run_max: not found
```

I therefore removed the option and got exim4 running again.

The only other queue configuration parameters I could find were in /etc/default/exim4 and these I have included below:

```
# /etc/default/exim4
EX4DEF_VERSION=''
# 'combined' -   one daemon running queue and listening on SMTP port
# 'no'       -   no daemon running the queue
# 'separate' -   two separate daemons
# 'ppp'      -   only run queue with /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/exim4.
# 'nodaemon' - no daemon is started at all.
# 'queueonly' - only a queue running daemon is started, no SMTP listener.
# setting this to 'no' will also disable queueruns from /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/exim4
QUEUERUNNER='combined'
# how often should we run the queue
QUEUEINTERVAL='5m'
# options common to quez-runner and listening daemon
COMMONOPTIONS=''
# more options for the daemon/process running the queue (applies to the one
# started in /etc/ppp/ip-up.d/exim4, too.
QUEUERUNNEROPTIONS=''
# special flags given to exim directly after the -q. See exim(8)
QFLAGS=''
# Options for the SMTP listener daemon. By default, it is listening on
# port 25 only. To listen on more ports, it is recommended to use
# -oX 25:587:10025 -oP /var/run/exim4/exim.pid
SMTPLISTENEROPTIONS='-oX 465:25 -oP /var/run/exim4/exim.pid'
```

My exim4 version is:

```
root@ds6419:/etc/exim4# exim4 --version
Exim version 4.80 #3 built 24-Jul-2014 03:28:10
Copyright (c) University of Cambridge, 1995 - 2012
(c) The Exim Maintainers and contributors in ACKNOWLEDGMENTS file, 2007 - 2012
Berkeley DB: Berkeley DB 5.1.29: (October 25, 2011)
Support for: crypteq iconv() IPv6 GnuTLS move_frozen_messages DKIM
Lookups (built-in): lsearch wildlsearch nwildlsearch iplsearch cdb dbm dbmjz dbmnz dnsdb dsearch nis nis0 passwd
Authenticators: cram_md5 plaintext
Routers: accept dnslookup ipliteral manualroute queryprogram redirect
Transports: appendfile/maildir/mailstore autoreply lmtp pipe smtp
Fixed never_users: 0
Size of off_t: 8
Configuration file is /var/lib/exim4/config.autogenerated
```

Can anybody help please?  Does the `queue_run_max` go somewhere else?  Or is there a different option for my version of exim4?

Comment: It looks like this option should be somewhere higher in your config file, try it to put after "domainlist".

Answer (score 0):

You are using a Debian exim4 split config (you're likely using a Debian or Ubuntu based distro).  When referring to Debian based systems, we always specifically say **exim4** to indicate that it's a non-default exim configuration.

The file you are editing is a template configuration file, not the actual file that Debian's exim4 reads.  The Debian init scripts read the contents of that file and several template files in /etc/exim4/, and assembles a standard exim4.conf file from them.  You'll want to read at http://pkg-exim4.alioth.debian.org/README/README.Debian.html for more detailed information.

Ultimately the answer is "if Debian's configuration has exposed that particular setting to your control", which is a bit uncertain.  Others here may know the Debian Exim4 configuration controls a lot better.  There is also an Exim4 specific mailing list that you can likely get the authoritative answers at http://lists.alioth.debian.org/mailman/listinfo/pkg-exim4-users.